# Is it worth buying SharePoint Conference videos?

Tags: 2013, training

I understand this is not really a useful community question. Pardon me for that.

The MS [SharePoint Conference videos](http://sharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx) are available for 200$. I was wondering, if it will be really helpful to purchase these now, considering the fact few videos would be based on beta( I know 2013 RTM'ed before the conference). Still, I am not sure about it. Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was there and have all the videos, but tbh I haven't looked at a them yet. I find them kinda unstructured for "learning", for me its more for an update on what is new and possible in 2013. For video learning I use sites like pluralsight, and for specific stuff there is tons of blog posts and tutorials on the internet now.